# (Python/Pandas) Divide two columns of pivoted dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I generated the following pandas dataframe after pivotting my data:

```
df_pivot=df.pivot_table(
values=[1911, 1912, 1916, 1917], index=['h_code','h_name'], 
columns=['sort_code', 'reg','c_name','c_code']
)
```

I would now like to add a column to my `df` (let's call it `c_new`) based on the result of dividing values for 1917 by values for 1911, for each 'h_name', but for the same `c_name`. Therefore, Each `c_name` should then have a value resulting from this division (`=1917/1911`) for each row of `h_name`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add sample data with expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select by top level, create same names of level and divide with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
a = df_pivot.xs(1917, axis=1,level=0, drop_level=False).rename(columns={1917:'out'})
b = df_pivot.xs(1911, axis=1,level=0, drop_level=False).rename(columns={1911:'out'})
```

Or:

```
a = df_pivot[[1917]].rename(columns={1917:'out'})
b = df_pivot[[1911]].rename(columns={1911:'out'})

df_pivot = df_pivot.join(a/b)
```